# Is there a way to display background-image url without encoding?

Tags: mediawiki

As topic? Can I have mediawiki displays background-url normally without the base64 encoding? What is the advantage of having it encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you don't mind editing the code. Edit includes/libs/CSSMin.php and change:

```
const EMBED_SIZE_LIMIT = 0;
```

Base64 encoding images is a bit of a tradeoff. It makes the web page size slightly larger since you are embedding the image directly in the page, but it also decreases the number of requests your browser has to make to the web server (since it is requesting one less image).

Here is some analysis of base64 encoding images and what the benefits and drawbacks are: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to